# How to make a test condition work in TCL

Tags: string, tcl

```
% set HI 1
1
% if { [ info exists HI] && { $HI == 1 } } { puts "Hello World "}
can't use non-numeric string as operand of "&&"
%
```

Either of the conditions can be tested alone. How to make the && of the tests work in TCL?

This alone works

```
% if  { $HI == 1 }  { puts "Hello World "}
Hello World
```

And this works alone too.

```
% if { [ info exists HI]  } { puts "Hello World "}
Hello World
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the extra curly braces; this should work fine:

```
if { [info exists HI] && $HI == 1 } { puts "Hello World" }
```

Answer (score 5):

The second part of your test, that is

```
{ $HI == 1 }
```

is wrong, because I suppose you made a confusion about the meaning of braces in Tcl. Braces *are not* the same of `( ... )`, they can't be used in a mathematical expression to change the priority used in evaluation.

Braces are used to compose a string containing spaces and make it appear as a single argument to a Tcl command, but *without* performing substitutions inside of it.

In your case, the `$HI` is not substituted with the value of the `HI` variable, so you are forming a string containing all the exact characters you see inside the braces, including the leading and the trailing spaces.

If you do

```
if {{ $HI == 1 } eq {$HI == 1}} {
    puts "same"
} else {
    puts "not the same"
}
```

you'll get `not the same` as result. (The `eq` performs string comparison inside an expression.)

You wan't get the right meaning neither if you use the double quote character as string delimiter, that is

```
" $HI == 1 "
```

In this case, your variable is actually substituted with its value, so its like you have directly written (supposing `$HI` is `1`, as in your code):

```
" 1 == 1 "
```

but it's string, *again*.

Why Tcl complains? As it says, you are trying to use a *non numeric string* as operand of `&&`, and `{ $HI == 1 }` is *not numeric* because there is no way to see is as a number, so Tcl can't convert to a true/false value depending on the number (false if 0, true if not 0), and the error occurs.

I think what you really wanted to write was

```
if { [ info exists HI] && ( $HI == 1 ) } { puts "Hello World "}
#                         ^          ^
#                         |__________|____ note ( ) instead of { }
```

to give higher priority to the `==` with respect to `&&`, or to make the conditional more clear. `expr`, which is implicitly called inside the test condition of an `if`, *knows* about the round brackets with the same meaning you find in other programming languages and in math: changing the evaluation order.

As it has been pointed out in other answers and comments, you really don't need the brackets, there, because (as in C and many other languages) the equal operator `==` has a higher priority than the boolean and `&&`. But if you want, you can use `( ... )` without fear:

```
if {2 - 1 * 2} { puts yes } { puts no }
```

gives `no`, because the expression is evaluated as `2 - (1 * 2)` which is 0.

```
if {(2 - 1) * 2} { puts yes } { puts no }
```

gives `yes` because `(2 - 1) * 2` is 2.

Comment: Strictly, `==` does numeric equality if both arguments are numeric, and string equality otherwise. `eq` skips the “are these numeric” bit and goes straight to string equality.

Comment: Absolutely! I just introduced the `eq` in my answer, and said a word about it.

Comment: @MarcoPallante. Thanks for very nice explanation of underlying principles.

Answer (score 1):

Try to `[expr $HI == 1]` instead of `{ $HI == 1 }`

Comment: (Note to @RatnendraPandey.) This answer is valid as well; an `if` statement's conditional block is passed through `expr` implicitly. So, your version is evaluated as `eval {[info exists HI] && {$HI == 1}}` which fails, but `eval {[info exists H] && $HI == 1}` succeeds, and so does `eval {[info exists HI] && [expr $HI == 1]}`, though more verbose.

Comment: Thanks acheong and triclosan  for the answers. 
The more I think about it, it seems to me that braces in `{ $HI == 1 }` prevent evaluation of `$HI == 1` giving it an appearance of string. That is why the two condition could not be successfully tested together. What do you say?

Comment: @RatnendraPandey - That's exactly it; you've got it.

Comment: I don't advise using an unbraced expression; it is much slower (since it has to be recompiled _every_ time) and less safe (if `$HI` substitutes as `[exit]` you'll see the difference!)

Answer (score 1):

In a Tcl expression, `{`…`}` enclose a non-substituted literal. (Or a variable name if there's a `$` immediately before.) When you have an expression inside, that indicates that you should do either one of these:

- Change the `{`…`}` to `(`…`)`; parentheses have their normal mathematical interpretation inside expressions.
- Change the `{`…`}` to `[expr {`…`}]` so that the expression is really interpreted as such.

The bytecode out of the two cases is virtually identical, so in performance terms it's a wash. You should write whichever is clearer to you. (Myself, I hardly ever use the second form, reserving nesting `[expr]` in an expression context for cases where I want to have a *non-constant* expression fragment. That's actually pretty rare.)